DB2 SQL inserts are very slow when table has a primary key
I have a DB2 table (map_card_number) that takes 5 minutes to insert 1M rows of data when it has a primary key, compared to 11 seconds to insert the same 1M rows of data when the primary key is removed.
Here are the details.

The SQL create table has the following syntax without the primary key:

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MAP_CARD_NUMBER;
CREATE TABLE MAP_CARD_NUMBER
    (
        KEY_OF_MAP   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        VALUE_OF_MAP VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE (KEY_OF_MAP)
    );


The SQL create table has the following syntax with the primary key:

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MAP_CARD_NUMBER;
CREATE TABLE MAP_CARD_NUMBER
    (
        ID  INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
        KEY_OF_MAP   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        VALUE_OF_MAP VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (ID),
        UNIQUE (KEY_OF_MAP)
    );

I also have two stored procedures that handle populating the map_card_number table.

The first stored procedure selects from a customer table that contains 1M rows, creates a cursor, traverses each row, one at a time, replaces '41000' with '32888' of the card_number, and calls the second stored procedure to save '41000' as the key and '32888' as the value to the map_card_number table.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE POPULATE_CC_MAP()
    LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_card_number VARCHAR(25);
    DECLARE v_value VARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE v_counter INT DEFAULT 0;

    FOR row AS cur1 CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR
        SELECT card_number
        FROM customer
        ORDER BY id
        DO
            SET v_counter = v_counter + 1;          
            SET v_card_number = row.card_number;
            SET v_value = REPLACE(v_card_number,'41000','32888');

            CALL map_put_card_number(v_card_number, v_value);      
           
            IF v_counter = 10000 THEN
              COMMIT;
              SET v_counter = 0;
            END IF;  

        END FOR;
END;


The second stored procedure saves the key and the value to the map table.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MAP_PUT_CARD_NUMBER(IN p_key VARCHAR(255), IN p_value VARCHAR(1024))
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO map_card_number AS SOURCE
    USING (VALUES (p_key, p_value)) AS merge (key_of_map, value_of_map)
    ON SOURCE.KEY_OF_MAP = merge.key_of_map
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (key_of_map, value_of_map)
        VALUES (p_key, p_value);
END;

So, here are my questions:

Why is inserting drastically slower when the primary key is added than when a primary key is not added?
What corrections need to be made so that inserts with a primary key are nearly as fast as inserting without a primary key?

Thank you, in advance, to anyone who provides suggestions to help me resolve this challenge.

Your question is why inserting with a single unique index is so much slower than inserting with two unique indexes. What is your Db2-server platform and version exactly? Use platform specific Db2 tags (db2-luw, db2-zos, db2-400). How exactly are you measuring (i.e. with which tooling?) Have you examined any monitoring output to see where the time is being spent? Your code shows inefficient row by row processing which is always worse than set based approaches.

Also, why did you choose to implement it in an RBAR fashion instead of a single MERGE statement?

Thank you for your help. The platform is db2_luw, running within a Docker container on Ubuntu 24.04. Ubuntu runs within a Proxmox hypervisor on a GEEKOM AE8 Mini PC AMD Ryzen 7 8845HS and is allocated 250GB of a 2T SDD and 20GB RAM out of 96GB of RAM.
I can measure the time it takes to run because I can execute the SP from within DBVisualizer and see the timed results.

You said, "Your code shows inefficient row-by-row processing, which is always worse than set-based approaches." Could you please elaborate on an alternative solution?
Also, I'm not sure what you mean by RBAR fashion. However, I chose single merge because that's the Internet research I could uncover on DB2 for inserting into a table where duplicates may appear.
I've implemented nearly the same stored procedure solution for Oracle, MSSQL, Postgres, MySQL, and MariaDB, and all are inserting in under 30 seconds with both unique indexes.
I am open to any suggestions.

That IF v_counter = 10000 THEN COMMIT looks so suspicious... Why are you committing half way through? That's a recipe for disaster. Do a commit at the end of the procedure for a whole or nothing result. You don't want half consumed data.

I've done some research and now understand what RBAR means. In this case, I can use a set-based approach instead of RBAR, and I'm currently working on a query to implement that. However, there are other situations where I'll need to call MAP_PUT_CARD_NUMBER() within the conditions of a stored procedure that isn't set-based.
This leads me to question why the insert operation becomes excessively slow when the primary key is added. Even when using an RBAR approach, it shouldn't take more than 30 seconds. What might I have not configured?

I can remove the v_counter, but that won't speed it up; it just gets slower because the transaction gets larger; it's not the issue. I use this technique in many of my RBAR procedures when traversing billions of rows across multiple threads. The code that's not currently in the procedure calls another procedure to track the last completed transaction. So, if the system crashes for whatever reason during the processing, it can pick up where it left off on restart instead of starting over from scratch.

Here's an update. I've modified the code to a set-based approach.
MERGE INTO MAP_CARD_NUMBER AS DEST
USING (SELECT CARD_NUMBER AS key_of_map, REPLACE(CARD_NUMBER,'41000','32888') as value_of_map
FROM CUSTOMER) as SOURCE
ON DEST.KEY_OF_MAP = SOURCE.KEY_OF_MAP    
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (key_of_map, value_of_map) VALUES (SOURCE.KEY_OF_MAP, SOURCE.VALUE_OF_MAP);

With the primary key, it now takes 1m 38s; a massive improvement. However, when the primary key is removed, it takes 4s 374ms. So, the question remains: Why is insertion with a primary key so much slower?

I tried to mimic your scenario and see the same phenomena as you do. In the access plan, I see an additional NL-JOIN underestimated 25 times (40.000 vs 1 million rows). I'll see if I can figure something out
